Azure Log Analytics - Alerts on specific time
I have function app that runs one time at 02:00 every day. I would like to do an alert if there is no logs from this service at 03:00. I can see you cannot specify at what time an alerts i checked. Any ideas on how to solve this specific scenario?


Any ideas on how to solve this specific scenario?

Alerts check for 24 hrs that if the condition is met or not. If you want to check for particularly at 3, you have to choose a service like automation which starts at 3, like Azure Logic apps:
Firstly select a recurrence trigger then select at these hours parameter:

then select 3:

then use Run query and list results to get  logs and then use condition to check if the length of the body is greater than or equal to 1:
length(body('Run_query_and_list_results')?['value'])


Then in False, send the mail/sms :

This way you can send alerts by checking at particular time.
For further information refer this SO-Thread1 and  SO-thread2.
